# How to select files from /sites/default/files with IMCE filebrowser?

Tags: files

Somehow the settings of directories in the configuration of IMCE (7.x-1.7) is pointing to <root>/. which lets met start in the private_files directory but not in the (public) files directory.

I couldn't figure it out where to change this. I tried to set a path to the public files directory with <root>/.. but Drupal would not allow me.

The settings under Home>Administration>Configuration>Media is set  to:
Public file system path:  sites/default/files
Private file system patch: sites/default/files/private_files

Anybody having a clue ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new IMCE profile from

> admin/config/media/imce/profile

Don't forget to add the **Permitted file extensions** and **Directories** while creating the IMCE profile.

Answer (score 0):

Please do check the required permission , specially for Apache user, ie `www-data` as this is the user which operates on behalf of the server. If you want to check whether it is a permission or some other issue, you can use the following command ( `For temporary basis and not on production`) to change the permission of files directory.

`sudo chmod -R 775 /sites/default/files/`

and

`sudo chown -R root:www-data /sites/default/files/`

In place of root, use your usernamem who is the main owner of the directory or